# Finding elements from vectors which are divisible by two number

Tags: r

I want to extract all the elements from a vector which are divisible by x or Y
Again, I want to extract all the elements from a vector which are divisible by x and Y.
Actually I want to extract the elements divided by 5 or 7, in one vector, 5 and 7 in another vector. Y<- X[X %% 5 == 0];Y, Y<- X[X %% 7 == 0];Y, it is working separately.

Comment: Use `|` or `&` i.e. `(!(v1 %% 2))|(!(v1 %%3))`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: not working. Actually I want to extract the elements divided by 5 or 7, in one vector, 5 and 7 in another vector.  Y<- X[X %% 5 == 0];Y,    Y<- X[X %% 7 == 0];Y, it is working separately.

Answer (score 0):

We can write a function to return a list of elements which are divisible by `x` **AND** `y` and `x` **OR** `y`.

```
get_all_elements <- function(vec, x, y) {
   list(OR = vec[vec %% x == 0 | vec %% y == 0], 
        AND = vec[vec %% x == 0 & vec %% y == 0])
}

output <- get_all_elements(1:100, 5, 7)
output

#$OR
# [1] 5   7  10  14  15  20  21  25  28  30  35  40  42  45  49  50  55  56  60  63  
#     65  70  75  77  80 84  85  90  91  95  98 100

#$AND
#[1] 35 70

get_all_elements(1:100, 7, 9)
#$OR
# [1]  7  9 14 18 21 27 28 35 36 42 45 49 54 56 63 70 72 77 81 84 90 91 98 99

#$AND
#[1] 63
```

You can extract two vectors separately if needed by `output$OR` and `output$AND` respectively.